# Drag and drop text into SynEdit control

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop, synedit

I have a **TSynEdit** control on a form and I want to drag and drop the focused node text from a **TVirtualStringTree**. I would like it to behave in the same way as when you drag and drop the highlighted text within the **TSynEdit** control:

- As you drag over the **TSynEdit**, the caret should mark the current drop position.
- When the text is dropped, it should replace any text that is currently highlighted.
- The drop position should handle tabs correctly.

I have looked at the code in the **TSynEdit** *DragOver* event, but it uses several variables and procedures that I can't access in a descendant class as they are declared **private**.

I have checked all the **TSynEdit** demos and can't find one that addresses my needs.

Anybody managed to do this successfully?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can manage to reach your goal by assigning two events to your editor: DragOver/DragDrop.

1/ you test the validity in the *DragOver event*, you also move the caret by calling **GetPositionOfMouse**

```
Procedure TForm1.EditorDragOver(Sender,Source: TObject;X,Y: Integer; State: TDragState; Var Accept: Boolean);
Var
  LCoord: TBufferCoord;
  LMemo: TSynMemo;
Begin
  LMemo := TSynMemo(Sender);
  // In your case you would rather test something with your tree...
  Accept := Clipboard.AsText <> '';
  // "As you drag over the TSynEdit, the caret should mark the current drop position": OK
  If LMemo.GetPositionOfMouse(LCoord) Then
    LMemo.CaretXY := LCoord;
End;
```

2/ You use the editor commands in the *DragDrop event*, to clear the selection and to insert chars

```
Procedure TForm1.EditorDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X,Y: Integer);
Var
  LMemo: TSynMemo;
Begin
  LMemo := TSynMemo(Sender);
  // "When the text is dropped, it should replace any text that is currently highlighted." : OK
  If LMemo.SelAvail Then
    LMemo.ExecuteCommand( ecDeleteChar , #0, Nil );
  // Paste, same comment as previously, here it's just an example...
  LMemo.ExecuteCommand( ecPaste, #0, Nil );
End;
```

This would have to be a bit tweaked according to your context.

Answer (score 2):

AZ01's answer didn't do exactly what I wanted, but it did point me in the correct direction. Here's the code I eventually used:

```
procedure TfrmTemplateEdit.memTemplateDragDrop(Sender, Source: TObject; X,
  Y: Integer);
var
  InsertText: String;
  ASynEdit: TSynEdit;
  OldSelStart, DropIndex: Integer;
  LCoord: TBufferCoord;
begin
  // Set the Insert Text
  InsertText := 'The text to insert';

  // Set the SynEdit memo
  ASynEdit := TSynEdit(Sender);

  // Get the position on the mouse
  ASynEdit.GetPositionOfMouse(LCoord);

  // Find the index of the mouse position
  DropIndex := ASynEdit.RowColToCharIndex(LCoord);

  // Delete any selected text
  If (ASynEdit.SelAvail) and
     (DropIndex >= ASynEdit.SelStart) and
     (DropIndex <= ASynEdit.SelEnd) then
  begin
    // Store the old selection start
    OldSelStart := ASynEdit.SelStart;

    // Delete the text
    ASynEdit.ExecuteCommand(ecDeleteChar, #0, Nil);

    // Move the caret
    ASynEdit.SelStart := OldSelStart;
  end
  else
  begin
    // Position the caret at the mouse location
    ASynEdit.CaretXY := LCoord;
  end;

  // Insert the text into the memo
  ASynEdit.ExecuteCommand(ecImeStr, #0, PWideChar(InsertText));

  // Set the selection start and end points to selected the dropped text
  ASynEdit.SelStart := ASynEdit.SelStart - length(InsertText);
  ASynEdit.SelEnd := ASynEdit.SelStart + length(InsertText);

  // Set the focus to the SynEdit
  ASynEdit.SetFocus;
end;
```

The code seems to work correctly with selections, tabs and undo.